# Alt-Tab shows two application switchers on Unity

Tags: unity, graphics, gui, application-switcher

I started to have problems with my Ubuntu application switcher (<kbd>Alt</kbd> +  <kbd>Tab</kbd>) this morning. When I press <kbd>Alt</kbd> +  <kbd>Tab</kbd>, not only one, but two application switchers show up. Last night I customized some stuff using the Unity Tweak Tool. I thought I didn't touch the application switcher. So now it looks like this:

[image]

[YouTube video](https://youtu.be/CMxK9g3tqoQ)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer taken from an edit by the OP to their question:

> I solved this problem by disabling application switcher in CCSM (Compizconfig settings manager).

CCSM can be installed by the following command:

`$ sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager`

*edit for better understanding:* To get rid of the switcher-icons in the foreground and only keep the standard application-switcher-icons that come with a standard ubuntu installation, disable `static application switcher` within CCSM. Let the keybindings solely control the functions within the "switcher" submenu of `ubuntu-unity-plugin` of CCSM.