# ALT + TAB switcher shows preview over icons. How to fix?

Tags: 16.04, unity, shortcut-keys, application-switcher

The switcher doesn't switch the apps correctly. I think the issue began after I used Unity Tweak Tool.

[This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/894587/i-have-a-problem-with-the-ubuntu-application-switcher) is the same question but hasn't been answered. I can't comment or upvote the question because of my reputation so here I am posting it again.

Thanks in advance.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: There was actually an answer hidden in the question. I edited and extracted it to make it visible. Would you mind checking the question you linked again? It's not very detailed, but it might be enough of a hint.

Comment: Yeah, thanks for that. Fixed it. I was searching for an answer for a long time.